# DOJO Constructor Synchronous

Tags: javascript, dojo, synchronous

I have a problem tring to synchronize a DOJO constructor in Javascript.

I have a "class" MYCLASS whitch i need to instantiate:

MYCLASS.JS

```
define([
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dojo/_base/lang',
'dojo/when',
'dojo/Deferred',

], function(declare, lang, when, Deferred){

    return declare(null, {
        var1: null,
        var2: null,
        var3: [],

    constructor: function(options){
        this.var1 = options.var1;
        this.var2 = options.var2;
        this._doSomething(); 
    },

    _doSomething: function(){
        //Here the "var3" is completed.
        //Some code which needs more time with REST requests.
    }
});
});
```

Ok, then i need to get an instance of this in my controller:

```
var myInstance = new MYCLASS(options);
```

It works fine except for the var3, which is not filled.
I have read about "Deferred" or ""when", but I don't know how to apply it.

Thank you in advance,
Nacho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using deferreds doesn't make it synchronized, but it may solve your problem. What deferreds do is quite simple, they provide an API to reach asynchronous data.

For example, consider the following scenario:

```js
var myAsyncData = null;
// ...
// The following is some asynchronous code (could be a REST call)
setTimeout(function() {
    myAsyncData = 3;
}, 1000);
// ...
console.log(myAsyncData);
```

This will obviously log `null` because the data is asynchronously filled and at the moment you're logging, the request has not been finished yet.

To solve that, people could use deferreds, for example:

```js
var myDeferred = new Deferred();
var myAsyncData = myDeferred.promise;
// ...
// The following is some asynchronous code (could be a REST call)
setTimeout(function() {
    myDeferred.resolve(3);
}, 1000);
// ...
myAsyncData.then(function(myData) {
    console.log(myData);
});
```

What happens here is that the data is wrapped in some kind of an API, and it will actually print the `3`.
This works because in the `then()` part of the code, you're waiting for the data. But remember that the code block inside the `then()` function is by itself also asynchronous!

---

Back to your case. If you're using `dojo/request/xhr` then you don't have to use `dojo/Deferred` by yourself, because that module already uses deferreds internally.

What you should write is the following:

```js
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dojo/_base/lang',
    'dojo/request/xhr'
], function(declare, lang, xhr){

    return declare(null, {
        var1: null,
        var2: null,
        var3: null,

        constructor: function(options){
            this.var1 = options.var1;
            this.var2 = options.var2;
            this._doSomething(); 
        },

        _doSomething: function() {
            //Here the "var3" is completed.
            //Some code which needs more time with REST requests.
            this.var3 = xhr("rest/request", {
                handleAs: "json"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Then inside your code you should use:

```js
var myInstance = new MYCLASS(options);
myInstance.var3.then(function(var3Data) {
    console.log(var3Data); // This contains the actual value!
});
```

If you need to do some additional processing when you get the response of your REST service, then you could use deferreds, for example:

```js
_doSomething: function() {
    //Here the "var3" is completed.
    //Some code which needs more time with REST requests.
    var dfd = new Deferred();
    this.var3 = dfd.promise;

    xhr("rest/request", {
        handleAs: "json"
    }).then(function(myData) {
        dfd.resolve(myData.someProperty);
    });
}
```

But remember, using deferreds always involves three steps. First you have to create the deferred, then you have to resolve it, and to listen to resolved data, you should use the `then()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a good solution, but finally I solve the problem by using events [dojo/topic](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/topic.html).

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the use case. Asynchronous communication can be handles by deferreds/promises, callbacks or publish/subscribe.